# Listview display duplicate data on refresh

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

[image: Image for understanding the image on the left is displayed on click from main activity, it is perfect as needed. When scroll or new data updated the listview on the right]I have made a `listview` with image and text as elements. If the data is text it displays text and if it is image it displays image.

When i click button from `MainActivity` to the listview, the listview is displayed as needed, i.e images for image and text for text data.

The problem occurs when the listview activity is opened and any new data is inserted in db and the listview is refreshed. The data in the view is completely messed up. it shows image in the some of the text data.

But when i go back to the main activity and again come back to listview everything is perfect.

Can anyone please help me whats going wrong here.

I am using SimpleCursorAdaptor, CursorLoader.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private TextView from, data;

 private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

 private String TO_USER;
 ConnectionService  connService;
 boolean mBounded;  

 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
String[] projection = {MessageHelper.COLUMN_ID,
        MessageHelper.COLUMN_FROM,
            MessageHelper.COLUMN_DATA};
    String args[] ={ "cid","data"};
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, projection,   
                    MessageHelper.COLUMN_CONVERSATION_ID + " = ?" + " AND " + 
                    MessageHelper.COLUMN_EXIN + " =  ?" ,args, 
                    MessageHelper.COLUMN_RECIEVED_TIMESTAMP);
              return cursorLoader;
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter();
     getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}



private void setListAdapter() {
     String[] columns = new String[] {
                MessageHelper.COLUMN_FROM,
                MessageHelper.COLUMN_DATA
              };

              int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.data
               };

              Cursor cursor = loadMessage();
              cursor.moveToFirst();
              dataAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(
                        this,
                        R.layout.linear_listitem,
                        cursor,
                        columns,
                        to,
                        0);

              listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
.

}


public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
     dataAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}

 protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
 }

 protected void onRestart(){
     super.onRestart();
    }
```

CursorAdapter.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
//import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.expert.sqllite.MessageChat;
import com.expert.sqllite.MessageHelper;

public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Map<Integer, ArrayList<MessageChat>> chatMapConId = new HashMap<Integer, 

ArrayList<MessageChat>>();  
public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,          int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to,flags);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService

(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {



    MessageChat msgchat = new MessageChat();
       msgchat.setData(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MessageHelper.COLUMN_DATA)));
      msgchat.setFrom(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MessageHelper.COLUMN_FROM)));


    ViewHolder  holder;
    if(!msgchat.getData().contains("-image-")){

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }


            TextView dataMsg =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.data);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams 

(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            ImageView imgMsg =null;



            if(msgchat.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase("me"))
            {

                if(!msgchat.getData().contains("-image-")){
                    dataMsg.setBackgroundResource

(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                    dataMsg.setText(msgchat.getData());

                }
                else
                {
                    String[]         imageSplit=msgchat.getData().split("-image-");
                    Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(imageSplit[1]);
                    try {
                        imgMsg (ImageView)view.findViewById

(R.id.chat_image);
                        imgMsg.setImageBitmap(getThumbnail

(imgUri,context));




                              dataMsg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            }

            else
            {

                if(!msgchat.getData().contains("-image-")){
                    dataMsg.setBackgroundResource

(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                    dataMsg.setText(msgchat.getData());
                }
                else{
                    String[]   imageSplit=msgchat.getData().split("-image-");
                    Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(imageSplit[1]);
                    try {
                        imgMsg =(ImageView)view.findViewById

(R.id.chat_image);
                        imgMsg.setImageBitmap(getThumbnail

(imgUri,context));
                        imgMsg.setBackgroundResource

(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                    dataMsg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

            }

            if(!msgchat.getData().contains("-image-")){
            dataMsg.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            dataMsg.setTextColor(R.color.textColor);
            }
            else{
                imgMsg.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            }



}



@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File imageFile;
    View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_listitem, parent, false);

    View rowViewImage = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_listitem_image,  parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    ViewHolderImage holderImage = null;

    String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MessageHelper.COLUMN_DATA));
    String path = null;
    if(data.contains("-image-")){
    path = data.split("-image-")[1];
    }

        holder = new ViewHolder();

           holder.data = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.data);
           holder.imageHolder =   (ImageView)rowViewImage.findViewById(R.id.chat_image);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
            return rowView;

    }

class ViewHolder
{   
    TextView data,from;
    ImageView imageHolder ;
}
class ViewHolderImage
{   
    ImageView imageHolder ;
}

public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri,Context context) throw    FileNotFoundException,IOException{
    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither=true;//optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? 

onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

   // double ratio = (originalSize > THUMBNAIL_SIZE) ? (originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE):   1.0;
    double ratio = 1.0;
    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2;

    bitmapOptions.inMutable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inDither=true;//optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig=Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;//optional
    bitmapOptions.outHeight=150;
    bitmapOptions.outWidth=150;
    input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();
    //bitmap.setWidth(400);
    //bitmap.setHeight(400);
    return bitmap;
}

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio){
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int)Math.floor(ratio));
    if(k==0) return 1;
    else return k;
}
```

}

**Update**
If i have data only text or only image. Then the list view is perfect. The problem i think is when both the view i.e text and image comes into picture.

Comment: How do you refresh your listview?

Comment: cursorloader using synch

Comment: It is problem of binding data, if you post your adapter then we can solve your problem

Comment: But at first when listview is loaded first it is perfect,  the problem occurs when new data is added async or scroll. and when i go back and aain come back it is perfect

Comment: I think you should call notifydatasetcahnged();

Comment: Have you used Viewholder? Im sure that your adapter is recycling the views, so that the problem occurs. Post your code then only we can suggest you the solutions.

Comment: @AshishBhatia if you know what the problem is, and how to fix it then you don't need to ask the question. If you don't know what the problem is, and someone asks you to post your code so we can help, then arguing with them isn't going to help

Comment: I have posted the code, notify is there on contentprovier whenevr the data has been changed

Comment: Where is your onCreateLoader() callback in your Activity implementing LoaderCallbacks?

Comment: sorry missed that part in copy paste. I have updated the code.

Comment: add dataadpter.notifydatasetchanged() before  listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Comment: @Giridharan added .notifydatasetchanged but not working. same problme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    return getItemViewType(cursor);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

These method has solved the problem of improper display