# custom cursoradaptor not working properly with view

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am working on the listview. I have used custom cursor adapter with newbind and bindview overridden with viewholder.
Whenever the listview is opened first time the newbind is called and then the bindview for each row. And the list is displayed.
When on listview, the data changes, the listview should be updated with the new row. My question is:

- On updating new row  to the existing listview, only bindview is called? or newbind is called first and then the bindview?
- In my case only bindview is getting called and it uses the previous holder instance and update the same.
- Whats the default behavior when listview is updated with custom simplecursoradaptor with holder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: where i need to write this. in activity i have adapter.swapcursor in onLoadFinished and onLoaderreset

Comment: You have to requery and then notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: ok will try that. Can you please help me out with the questions and behavior as i am new  to android.

Comment: sure please post issue. if u had

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154275/listview-display-duplicate-data-on-refresh , I had posted one issue in the link. Will the solution you mentioned will work in the link?

Answer (score 0):

## Use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

before you set adapter like:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);
    return getItemViewType(cursor);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

These method has solved the problem of improper display